# Cannot connect to OpenCV manager

Tags: android, opencv

So I have an application that runs on it's own and I tried adding OpenCV support. I'm using the async initialization approach. Basically copied the code from the tutorial at under

**How to use OpenCV library project in your application**

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

Anyway, when I run my application the log shows

```
"Trying to load OpenCV library"
"Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager"
```

I even put a log statement before the switch statement and it never shows up meaning it never gets there. So I'm a bit lost

Comment: Did you install the opencv apks to your device/emulator before starting your app (see your link, section 2, under "Application development with async initialization")

Answer (score 0):

Please, install OpenCV Manager(you can find it on Google Play) on your device/emulator